# HTML js input accessibility for blind people or unpowered screen on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, accessibility

HTML page has 3 (or at least 2) buttons (and some audio signals that indicates it). I want to know a way to people can work with it without eyes or to save electricity by **turning SCREEN OFF**. By only use of Android hardware buttons, headphones buttons or touchscreen (if is there a way to use it while screen is off). Good accelerometers or compass is not on all phones and i doubt it has JS API and can be used for this.
It have to be lunching on PC and Android 6+ (without external keyboard or voice to text) offline. Clean HTML5, vanilla JS.

With external keyboard it is obvious. On Android I know there is some buttons (volume) that work while screen is off and also buttons on the headphones (but all my 3 cheap headphones has strange and different behavior so i cant even test it).

The question is not about how to make it text-to-speach friendly or voice commands. Nor about special browsers, additional software or hardware.

```html
<style>
body{margin:0}
.btn_top{width:100%;height:50vh}
.btn_l {width:48%;height:50vh}
.btn_r {width:48%;height:50vh; position:absolute; right:0px}
</style>
<button class='btn_top' onclick="console.log('up')">up</button>
<button class='btn_l' onclick="console.log('accept')">accept</button>
<button class='btn_r' onclick="console.log('next')">next</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/WAI-ARIA_basics

Answer (score 1):

You are using real <button> elements so that's [the first (and recommended) way to achieve accessibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) - using the proper semantic elements. Your buttons have embedded text so the text will be read by screen readers and surfaced to other assistive technology (such as a braille device).  And since you have text in your buttons, a speech interface user can say *"click up"* or *"click accept"*.

So the code you currently have is very accessible and there's nothing else you have to do.

Comment: The human turned his screen off. Now he want to send some command by his hand to HTML application. Using voice is absolute last thing,   because this will disturb other people and cause tired throat, and noise level can prevet this. Buying or DIYing external devices is also unacceptable

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are familiar with various assistive technologies that people use. You are guessing at what their experience will be like.

Comment: If i cant use it by myself (i need this soft, i know what i need), how can i expect more from users, some of them has no internet connection never from time of buying smartphone. The task is simple - press button while screen is OFF, so to do it we have to DIY arduino 2-key controller, or buy external keyboard or mod phone to disable only LCD but not touch somehow